# Handling a remote connection exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

The desired result from this script is to find out the PowerShell version on a list of hosts. I would like to handle the exception when the remote machine is down or does not have remoting enabled. However, the `catch` does not appear to be entered. Just the standard red flaming error message from PowerShell appears.

What do I need to do to catch the exception?

```
X:\Scripts\PSAutomation> Get-Content .\get-versions.ps1
server_list = @(
   'CAPPY'
)

$server_list |
   ForEach-Object {
       Try {
           Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion}
       }
       Catch
       {
           Write-Host "Failed to connect to $_"
       }
   }
X:\Scripts\PSAutomation> .\get-versions.ps1
[CAPPY] Connecting to remote server CAPPY failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the
request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer CAPPY. Verify
that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see
the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (CAPPY:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `ErrorAction` for that call to `stop`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "sdf" {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion} -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Using `-ErrorAction` causes the red message to appear in the normal console text color. However, nothing about `Write-Host` ever appears.

Comment: I think you are wrong, the message should start with Failed to connect....Thats because $_ in your catch block represents the error instead of the current foreach-object pipeline variable. You probably have to introduce a variable before you try, like: `$current = $_` and use `$current` instead of `$_` in your Write-Host

Answer (score 1):

I actually encountered a very similar situation in which I had a long list of PCs, but some were offline, and some I didn't have access to. In addition, there were some I *did* have access to, that would encounter a non-terminating error that beings with 'Failed to Initialize Drives'. This is why I couldn't use try/catch or something that would stop for any error. I might've been able to use targeted catch's, but I used the -ErrorVariable parameter from Invoke-Command to save whatever error each Invoke-Command encountered to a variable (I called mine $stoperror). Here is a simplified version of the snippet from my code:

```
$computers = get-content $(Read-Host "enter path list .txt file")
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Write-Host "Pinging $computer..."
    $ping_result = Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($ping_result) {
      $query_result = invoke-command -computername $computer -errorvariable stoperror -scriptblock {
        Write-Host "Accessed $env:COMPUTERNAME" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        # this is where you can check the $stoperror variable, for whatever errors you're looking for
        if (($stoperror -like "*Access is denied*") -or ($stoperror -like "*WinRM cannot complete the operation*")) {
            write-host $stoperror
            Write-Host "$computer got an access denied or winrm operation error!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "$computer is down!" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

The tricky part is when you use that -errorvariable parameter and define the variable, you don't have to use a $.

Also, you may be able to do a ping test right off the bat to test for connectivity. It may help save time down the line, the Invoke-Command errors always take longer than a ping for me.

Please let me know if this helps.